# Windows Garageband equivalent

Tags: windows, music-production

### Required

- Record MIDI input from physical MIDI instruments
- Use MIDI instruments
- Export to mp3 or other common audio format
- Open audio files and include in project
- Multiple audio tracks
- Change track volume
- Under $30

### Optional(but nice)

- Free
- Edit recorded MIDI
- Open/load MIDI form file
- Download and use MIDI instruments
- Record MIDI input from virtual keyboard

Comment: Does it have to be free? And if not, what's your maximum budget?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a cross-platform application named [LMMS](http://lmms.sourceforge.net/home.php) (Linux Multimedia Studio):

- runs on Windows too despite its name
- free and open-source
- it has MIDI support
- can export to `ogg` and `wav`
- can include audio files (probably only `ogg` and `wav`)
- it has a gallery of `ogg` samples and instruments
- multiple tracks with independent volume
- supports [VST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Studio_Technology) plugins

[image]